# Gradle Variant : import

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use gradle variant, to have multiple apk.
I have a class "Config", but this class will be different for each project.
In the MainActivity, I want to import this Config class. How can I do to choose the right class ?

- **ch.mycompany.main**
- MainActivitiy
- **ch.mycompany.projectA**
- Config
- **ch.mycompany.projectB**
- Config

(*ProjectA, ProjectB and Main are in the same Android module.*)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import an existing class file in project (Using Eclipse)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578945/import-an-existing-class-file-in-project-using-eclipse)

Comment: projectA, projectB and main are in the same android module.